# Android : Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe

Tags: android

Bascially i'm trying to add the back functionality using 
(MinSDK is set to 11)

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Here are is my function:

```
public class DetailActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detail_layout);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


}
```

The Logcat Details:

```
07-28 18:26:50.030  19793-19795/? E/art﹕ Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `getActionBar()` try this: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`

Comment: Can you add some explanation as what this change does and why it will fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `AppCompactActivity` in place of `ActionBarActivity`.

And change the function `getActionBar` 
to `getSupportActionBar`