# Deletion of value from Firebase causing app to crash and restart

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

There is a FloatingActionButton which allows you to change your imageView. As soon as an image view is set up it changes the imageUrl key in my Firebase database to the new image that has been added. This is working fine however, I am trying to delete the previous image from my Firebase Storage as I do not want unnecessary images to be present.

The current image uri is stored in Saved Preferences and then used when you press the button the button to change it.
Every time I press this button and select an image from my Gallery,

1) my app crashes, and I have to login again.

Once I have logged again, the new image is shown,

2) however it doesn't get deleted from my FirebaseStorage.

I would like to solve both these problems.

Moi_Frag.java

```
package com.example.admin.college20;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;

public class Moi_Frag extends Fragment {
    ImageView imageView;
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
    private static final int GALLERY_INTENT = 1;
    private Uri imageUri = null;
    TextView text_name, text_email;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private String uid;
    StorageReference storageReference;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_moi__frag, container, false);

        imageView = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
        text_name = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.moi_name);
        text_email = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.moi_email);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());

        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

            uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
            final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference().child("Users").child(uid);

            ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    final String name = user.getName();
                    final String email  = user.getEmail();
                    final String imageUrl = user.getImageUrl();
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(imageUrl.toString());

                    SharedPreferences moiPref =  getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = moiPref.edit();
                    editor.putString("uriLastSeg", uri.getLastPathSegment());
                    editor.commit();

                    text_name.setText(name);
                    text_email.setText(email);
                    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT);
            }
        });
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            imageUri = data.getData();
            if(imageUri!=null){
                imageUploading();
            }
        }
    }
    private void imageUploading() {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Changing Yo Pic");
        progressDialog.show();
        final SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String id = pref.getString("uriLastSeg", "");
        final StorageReference prevFilepath = storageReference.child("Images").child(id);
        StorageReference filepath = storageReference.child("Images").child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());
        filepath.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                prevFilepath.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                Uri uri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                final String uid1 = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                Map<String,Object> taskMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(uid1);

                taskMap.put("imageUrl", uri.toString());

                databaseReference.updateChildren(taskMap);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_moi__frag.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_black_24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="230dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:id="@+id/background_image"
                android:src="@drawable/moibackground"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/error"
                app:civ_border_width="2dp"
                app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
                android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name here"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:id="@+id/moi_name"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/moi_email"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Email"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

User.java

```
package com.example.admin.college20;


public class User {
    private String imageUrl, name, email;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String imageUrl, String name, String email) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {this.email = email;}
}
```

Comment: Can you attach your crash logs ?

Comment: The app crashes and restarts so I don't know how to save or check the previous log but after the app starts, this is how the log looks


03-18 18:39:23.155 13512-13512/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni

03-18 18:39:23.176 13512-13520/? E/art: Failed writing handshake bytes (-1 of 14): Broken pipe

03-18 18:39:23.176 13512-13520/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active

Comment: I think you are concerned about wrong problem here, I hope [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31683538/4112725) might help you. And if it is, then the error is not related to Firebase